# JPQL EclipseLink Error Union Select

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to get the distinct file name from the user that has access to and department's file. When I run it separate two queries both are fine like this:

```
Query q12 = CpabeDAO.em.createQuery("SELECT f.realName FROM FileObject f JOIN f.listUserAccessor d WHERE d.id=:userID");
        q12.setParameter("userID", 401);
        List<String> res = q12.getResultList();
        for(String a : res){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        Query q13 = CpabeDAO.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT f.realName FROM FileObject f JOIN f.listDeptAccessor d WHERE d.departmentId=:deptID");
        q13.setParameter("deptID", 1);
        List<String> res2 = q13.getResultList();
        for(String a : res2){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

But when I tried to combine both queries using UNION as it is explained [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_union.htm), like this:

```
Query q12 = CpabeDAO.em.createQuery("SELECT f.realName FROM FileObject f JOIN f.listUserAccessor d WHERE d.id=:userID UNION SELECT a.realName FROM FileObject a JOIN a.listDeptAccessor w WHERE w.departmentId=:deptID");
        q12.setParameter("userID", 401);
q12.setParameter("deptID", 1);
        List<String> res = q12.getResultList();
        for(String a : res){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

It gave me error as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT DISTINCT t3.REALNAME FROM DEPT_FILE_ACCESS t5, DEPARTMENT t4, FILE' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: (SELECT t0.REALNAME FROM FILEOBJECT t0, USER_FILE_ACCESS t2, USER t1 WHERE ((t1.ID = ?) AND ((t2.fileHasAccess_ID  = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t2.user_id))) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT t3.REALNAME FROM DEPT_FILE_ACCESS t5, DEPARTMENT t4, FILEOBJECT t3 WHERE ((t4.DEPARTMENTID = ?) AND ((t5.fileHasAccess_ID  = t3.ID) AND (t4.DEPARTMENTID = t5.dept_id)))))
    bind => [401, 1]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=FileObject sql="(SELECT t0.REALNAME FROM FILEOBJECT t0, USER_FILE_ACCESS t2, USER t1 WHERE ((t1.ID = ?) AND ((t2.fileHasAccess_ID  = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t2.user_id))) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT t3.REALNAME FROM DEPT_FILE_ACCESS t5, DEPARTMENT t4, FILEOBJECT t3 WHERE ((t4.DEPARTMENTID = ?) AND ((t5.fileHasAccess_ID  = t3.ID) AND (t4.DEPARTMENTID = t5.dept_id)))))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    at cpabe.service.UserRegistration.main(UserRegistration.java:351)
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Can you try executing this SQL query independent of EclipseLink using a simple JDBC connection? From a glance, the generated query `SELECT t0.REALNAME FROM FILEOBJECT t0, USER_FILE_ACCESS t2, USER t1 WHERE ((t1.ID = 401) AND ((t2.fileHasAccess_ID  = t0.ID) AND (t1.ID = t2.user_id))) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT t3.REALNAME FROM DEPT_FILE_ACCESS t5, DEPARTMENT t4, FILEOBJECT t3 WHERE ((t4.DEPARTMENTID = 1) AND ((t5.fileHasAccess_ID  = t3.ID) AND (t4.DEPARTMENTID = t5.dept_id))))` looks correct.

Comment: @WillDazey it works by giving the file name, but what is the equivalent in jpql?

Comment: What "works by giving the file name"? The SQL query I provided?

Comment: @WillDazey I meant it gave the result as expected. I checked with the SQL you gave and the one generated from jpql it is same but only the extra bracket in front and end of statement gave error when I run in jdbc